# Best way to ignore certain imported functions in jest tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, axios

I'm working with Jest to test vue components. I don't want to test the axios calls inside of some of my functions, as I want the calls to be tested in a different place.

The way my files are set up, I import a function that builds an axios call into my component, like this:

My Component:

```
import { RepositoryFactroy } from '../services/RepositoryFactory';
const ModelRepo = RepositoryFactory.get('model');

export default {
  methods: {
    async getModelItems() {
      ModelRepo.get(); //calls an axios get for all matching records, needs to be mocked
      OtherCodeThatNeedsToBeRun(); //this needs to run
    }
  }
}
```

The Repository Factory gets a matching repository for whatever you are looking for, in this case "model", and checks the corresponding repository for example `ModelRepository.js` for a list of functions that have whatever info is needed for an axios call, then add it onto the axios instance declared in `Repository.js`. Not sure if that's necessary info but just want to be thorough.

Say I wanted to test something on `Component.vue` in `getModelItems()` method without running my imported axios call. How do I make Jest ignore the `ModelRepo.get()` call? Do I somehow have to create a jest mock for this?

**edit**

To be clear, I need `getModelItems()` to run for other code inside it, and only to replace the functionality of `ModelRepo.get()` within that method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could mock that specific module before mounting the component:

```js
jest.mock('@/services/RepositoryFactory', () => ({
  RepositoryFactory: {
    get: () => ({
      get: () => {}
    })
  }
}))

describe('HelloWorld', () => {
  it('foo', () => {
    shallowMount(HelloWorld)
  })
})
```

Comment: does this also work for entire imports vs just a single function?